# Check If input contains value or another value

Tags: javascript, textarea

I am stuck on trivial issue, how to simply check if textarea contains "12" OR "34" value? Why does the code attached below does not work?

```js
function check() {
    if (V1.value == ('12' || '34')) {
            alert('Yes');
        }
    else {
            alert("No");
        }
    }
```

```html
<textarea id="V1"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Comment: It should be `value === 12 || value === 34` because `value === ( 12 || 34)` transpiles into `value === 12` since 12 is not false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `if(V1.value == '12' || V1.value == '34')`.

`('12' || '34')` will simply evaluate to `"12"`, so your statement is just checking if the value is 12.

```js
function check() {
    if(V1.value == '12' || V1.value == '34') {
            alert('Yes');
        }
    else {
            alert("No");
        }
    }
```

```html
<textarea id="V1"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `V1.value === "12" || V1.value === "34"`.

Also you need to get the `#V1` input with:

```
const V1 = document.getElementById("V1");
```

```js
const V1 = document.getElementById("V1");

function check() {
  if (V1.value === "12" || V1.value === "34") {
    alert("Yes");
  } else {
    alert("No");
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="V1"></textarea>
<br />
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

---

This can be done in a much simple way:

```js
const V1 = document.getElementById("V1");

function check() {
  if (V1.value === "12" || V1.value === "34") alert("Yes");
  else alert("No");
}
```

```html
<textarea id="V1"></textarea>
<br />
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

---

You can do this in this way also:

```js
const V1 = document.getElementById("V1");

function check() {
  V1.value === "12" || V1.value === "34" ? alert("Yes") : alert("No")
};
```

```html
<textarea id="V1"></textarea>
<br />
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```